# maven can't find my local artifacts

Tags: maven

I can't seem to run `mvn -o package` because it complains with

> The repository system is off line but the artifact
>   com.liferay.portal:util-bridges:jar:6.1.20 is not available in the
>   local repository.

But I checked my local repository and that artifact does exist there. I also tried the solution of setting updatePolicy to never in the settings.xml file but that failed to work.

Comment: Does your settings.xml point to the repository you are checking ?

Comment: Is there a _maven.repositories file in the artifact's folder (.m2/repository/com/liferay/...)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven fails to find local artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517129/maven-fails-to-find-local-artifact)

Answer (score 93):

Prior to Maven 3.0.x, Maven did not track the origin of files in the local repository.

This could result in build issues, especially if you were building something that listed the (now dead) very borked java.net2 repository... Not only did that repository change released artifacts (extremely bad and evil practice) but it also published artifacts at the same coordinates as artifacts on central but with different content (unbelievably evil)

So you could have the build work (because you had commons-io:commons-io:2.0 from central) wipe your local repo and the build fails (because you now get commons-io:commons-io:2.0 from java.net2 which was a completely different artifact with different dependencies in the pom) *or* vice versa.

The above situation is one of the drivers for using a maven repository manager, because that allows you to control the subset of a repository that you expose downstream and the order in which artifacts are resolved from multiple repositories (usually referred to as routing rules)

In any case, when maven switched to Aether as the repository access layer, the decision was made to start tracking where artifacts come from.

So with Maven 3.0.x, when an artifact is downloaded from a repository, maven leaves a `_maven.repositories` file to record where the file was resolved from. If you are building a project and the effective list of repositories does not include the location that the artifact was resolved from, then Maven decides that it is as if the artifact was not in the cache, and will seek to re-resolve the artifact...

There are a number of bugs in 3.0.x though... The most critical being how `offline` is handled... Namely: when offline, maven 3.0.x thinks there are no repositories, so will always find a mismatch against the `_maven.repositories` file!!!

The workaround for Maven 3.0.x is to delete these files from your local cache, eg

```
$ find ~/.m2/repository -name _maven.repositories -exec rm -v {} \;
```

The side effect is that you loose the protections that Maven 3.0.x is trying to provide.

The good news is that Maven 3.1 will have the required fix (if we can ever get our act together and get a release out the door)

With Maven 3.1 when in offline mode the `_maven.repositories` file is (semi-)ignored, and there is also an option to ignore that file for online builds (referred to as legacy mode)

At this point in time (June 1st 2013) the 4th attempt to cut a release that meets the legal and testing requirements is in progress... So, assuming that the 4th time is lucky, I would *hope* to see 3.1.0-alpha-1 released in 3-4 days time... But it could be longer given that we want to give the changes in 3.1 enough time to soak to ensure uses builds don't break (there was a change in an API exposed (by accident-ish - the API is needed by the site and dependency plugin) that plugin authors have depended on (even though they shouldn't have) so there is potential, though we think we have all the bases covered)

Hope that answers your question (and maybe a few more you didn't know you had ;-) )

Comment: Thanks alot thats fixed it. I was checking the contents of these _maven.repositories files and it had some reference to the nexus server that was being used at my workstation at the office. I've copied the artifacts from my .m2 on that machine to my laptop so that might explain why it couldnt resolve that host. Anyways thought this might be a common thing people do ie copy local repositories across machines.

Comment: I'm still getting this problem with 3.3.9 on Ubuntu 16.04.  Can anyone else confirm?  Is this a regression?

Comment: I too am on Ubuntu 16.04 with 3.3.9,  and none of the suggested answers are working.

Comment: Using Maven 3.3.9; removing this file from everywhere still doesn't work. Keep getting .lastUpdated files (like Apache commons-io-2.5.jar) where real JARs and poms should be brought down.

Comment: If you want to bypass this origin check for a single scenario (without affecting the Maven cache), pass `aether.enhancedLocalRepository.trackingFilename=some_nonexistent_dummy_file_name` to the process; easiest way is to add a `-D` system property to the invocation command. You can also programmatically inject the key-value pair as a config property to Aether's `RepositorySystemSession`.

Comment: The `-Daether.enhancedLocalRepository.trackingFilename=some_nonexistent_dummy_file_name` property works! Thanks @JanakaBandara

Comment: I suppose this is technically right but if you're installing artifacts from an untrustworthy source I suspect your problems are going to end up a whole lot worse than a broken build.

Answer (score 41):

I also had to remove _remote.repositories in the same way as the _maven.repositories described above.  I'm using Maven 3.1.1

```
find ~/.m2/repository -name _remote.repositories -exec rm -v {} \;
```

Comment: This helped me a lot. I have Maven 3.2.5 and still this problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when i was using apache-maven-3.0.4, the issue is gone right after i move to apache-maven-3.3.1.

Comment: Cannot confirm that for maven 3.3.9. I had to delete all occurances of _remote.repositories and _maven.repositories. This issue drove me mad when dealing with company proxy issues and company managed repositories, in combination.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in Ubuntu Linux when I've installed local artifacts via a shell script. The solution was to delete the local artifacts and install them again "manually" - calling `mvn install:install-file` via terminal.