# Maven: Meaning of _remote.repositories file

Tags: java, maven

I try to figure it out what the .repositories files are for.

I've just downloaded the dsol/dsol-xml/1.6.9 and in this folder there is a '_remote.repositories' file. Its content is:

```
#NOTE: This is an Aether internal implementation file, its format can be changed without prior notice.
#Tue Sep 15 18:16:30 CEST 2015
dsol-xml-1.6.9.jar>simulation=
dsol-xml-1.6.9.pom>simulation=
```

What does this means?!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't get the close vote. Seems a pretty clear question to me, and a quick google didn't show anything up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gist from the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866978/maven-cant-find-my-local-artifacts)

> with Maven 3.0.x, when an artifact is downloaded from a repository,
>   maven leaves a _maven.repositories file to record where the file was
>   resolved from.