# My java project can't recognize a class from my other custom maven dependency from local repository

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies, mvn-repo

I have issues with Maven 3 / Intellij .

As you see in this picture , I can't use my custom dependency classes in a new different project. it seems that intellij (same issue with eclipse) does not recognize the class  **IRunnableTask.java** from the dependency **scheduler** (package : com.sifoklus.scheduler.task) although it's installed in my local maven repository and I can see it in External Libraries view in IntelliJ
[image: Screenshot of IntelliJ]

Here is my local repository path from setting.xml
[image: Screenshot with XML]

and the dependency is well installed in the same path :
[image: Screenshot of Windows Explorer]

and I added this dependency to my new project using :
[image: Screenshot of Maven dependencies XML in IntelliJ]

Intellij is using the right settings file and the right local repo
[image: Screenshot of Maven settings in IntelliJ]

I 've already tried to delete cache and restart . the problem is not fixed.

Do you know what is the problem and how it can be resolved ?
Thank you

I tried to delete cache and restart . nothing changed

[[EDIT]]

Hello @romanv-jb

the error in 'problem' view says : cannot resolve symbol sifoklus (name of one folder in the package) .
If I click more actions : one of the options is Add maven Dependency ,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8g11.png)

when I click on this option , the intellij pop up finds the dependency but when I choose it , nothing changes.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIi6J.png)

The code of Interface IRunnableTask is :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwnmS.png)

Comment: What does IDEA say in the Problems Tool Window? Can you share the exact error message it is giving you?
Can you share the "scheduler" artifact or a screenshot/code of how the "IRunnableTask" Interface is declared?

Comment: Hello @romanv-jb 

the error in 'problem' view says : cannot resolve symbol sifoklus (name of one folder in the package) .
If I click more actions : one of the options is Add maven Dependency , when I click on this option , the intellij pop up finds the dependency but when I choose it , nothing changes.
I will update the post with all screenshot . please see the update. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the directory structure inside the `com.sifoklus:scheduler` jar file, it appears the `repackage` goal of the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` was run during its build. All the `com.sifoklus.*` classes should appear at the root rather than under `BOOT-INF/classes`.

If indeed `scheduler` has the plugin spring-boot-maven-plugin defined in its POM file, with an execution goal of `repackage`, try removing this plugin, and rebuild `scheduler` using `mvn clean install`.

Comment: That was the solution.
I commented the block <build> in the pom.xml of scheduler.  now it does not build a fat jar but it resolves the problem. Thank you very much @Brian for this  help

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can try are:

- run mvn clean install -U
- update the maven dependencies from the side bar of intellij
- give a look to this question: [maven can't find my local artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866978/maven-cant-find-my-local-artifacts/16870552#16870552)

Comment: hello @HypedBudy I ve already ran mvn clean install -U and the dependency exists in the side bar. but I cant import it in my project. I will check the link you suggested . Thnak you

Comment: I ve already removed _remote.repositories file. but problem persists