# Maven message about artifacts being present locally but cached from remote repository

Tags: maven-3

Suddenly, running Maven 3.9.5 in GitLab with a cached .m2 repository mounted locally in the project, I am getting this message:

> [INFO] Artifact XXX is present in the local repository, but cached
> from a remote repository ID that is unavailable in current build
> context, verifying that is downloadable from [central
> (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]

The artifacts it is always checking are in one of the public repositories (central, jboss, etc.) and it is not even all of them - just a handful but enough to clutter the logs.

Nothing I seem to do resolves it.  I've seen you might be able to delete the "remote repository" files in the .m2 folder but I would prefer not to manipulate that.  I do not get this locally, only when running with the local .m2 mounted repository in a GitLab job.

Things I have tried:

- Clearing the GitLab cache
- Removing the `<repository/>` from the `pom.xml`
- Running with `mvn -U`

Interestingly, if kick off another pipeline build right after where I got the message, I do *not* see that logged message so it does not even happen consistently.

An example of the settings.xml:

```xml
<settings>
    <!-- Servers -->
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>companya</id>
            <username>companya-dev</username>
            <password>PASSWORD</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>companya-projects</id>
            <username>companya-dep</username>
            <password>PASSWORD</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>companya-releases</id>
            <username>companya-dep</username>
            <password>PASSWORD</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>companya-snapshots</id>
            <username>companya-dev</username>
            <password>PASSWORD</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>oss</id>
            <username>USERNAME</username>
            <password>PASSWORD</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>companya</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>companya</id>
                    <url>https://companya.com/repository/maven-public</url>
                    <layout>default</layout>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>companya-projects</id>
                    <url>https://companya.com/repository/maven-projects/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>companya-releases</id>
                    <url>https://companya.com/repository/maven-releases/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>companya-snapshots</id>
                    <url>https://companya.com/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>oss</id>
            <properties>
                <gpg.executable>gpg</gpg.executable>
                <gpg.passphrase>PASSWORD</gpg.passphrase>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <!-- Active Profile -->
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>companya</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
    <!-- Plugin Groups -->
    <pluginGroups>
        <pluginGroup>org.sonatype.plugins</pluginGroup>
    </pluginGroups>
</settings>
```

Comment: Do you use the correct coodirnates (GAV) ... ?

Comment: Yes. The POMs work properly locally and if I run the build multiple times in sequence on the CI side it will not always give that message.

Comment: That sounds like network/proxy/firewall issues...Are the settings.xml on the CI correctly configured ?

Comment: Nothing has changed seriously in 1+ year except upgrading Maven. All the settings are correct, they do work in the CI/CD, locally, and everywhere else.  The issue appears and then goes away if another build runs immediately after.  This only happens in the CI/CD side but I cannot pinpoint why.

Comment: That looks: `https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2` like you are using not a repository inside your company or your settings.xml is wrong...

Comment: I've attached an example of the `settings.xml` that is used in GitLab.  If the settings are wrong (which they could be) then I would expect every other Java project to have the same problem but it is specific to this repository (which could be related to the GL caching - but also, every project is using the same template).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason this seems to resolve the issue (mostly, because I get 1 or 2 occasionally with the same warning?). I am not trying to mirror anything, just use Maven Central for dependencies that are public and our own repository for a handful of private dependencies. This is real specific to being run in GitLab with caching because it does not happen locally.

I can somewhat replicate it locally as well but playing around with the repos in my own `settings.xml` and get the same warning.

I added Maven Central 1st to my list of repositories and moving our own public last.  In between are the release and snapshot repos:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to the `_remote.repositories` file in your local repository. See [maven can't find my local artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866978/maven-cant-find-my-local-artifacts)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using a internal dependency from a private repository.
When I removed it from my local repository, I saw it downloaded it just fine when I ran mvn clean compile again.

The issue was, that this dependency was also listed as a dependency for one of my plugins that I defined in my pom.

Taking a closer look at my .m2/settings.xml and comparing it with a co-worker revealed the issue: I was lacking the private repository as plugin repository. Hence the message from maven that it unavailable in the current build context.