# Maven can't find package

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am developing a project in maven, and I have created 2 modules, one for the entities
Here the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.fakenews.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>fakenewsCommons</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>fakenewsCommons</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And the other module makes use of this one through dependencies in the pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.fakenews.scraper.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>fakenewsScraperApi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>fakenewsScraperApi</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fakenews.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>fakenewsCommons</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have already compiled the first module with the entities with

> mvn clean install

and I have verified that:

1. the .jar has been created in the folder ~ / .m2 / repository / com / fakenews / commons / fakenewsCommons / 0.0.4-SNAPSHOT

[image]

2. I have decompiled the jar to check that the classes are there
   [image]

but when i compile the main module with

> mvn clean install

maven can't find the package.

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/service/NewService.java:[3,55] package com.fakenews.commons.fakenewsCommons.models.dao does not exist
```

Here the output with

> mvn clean install -e

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------< com.fakenews.scraper.api:fakenewsScraperApi >-------------
[INFO] Building fakenewsScraperApi 0.0.4-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ fakenewsScraperApi ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ fakenewsScraperApi ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ fakenewsScraperApi ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/service/NewService.java:[3,55] package com.fakenews.commons.fakenewsCommons.models.dao does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/service/NewService.java:[4,58] package com.fakenews.commons.fakenewsCommons.models.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/service/INewService.java:[3,58] package com.fakenews.commons.fakenewsCommons.models.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/service/NewService.java:[14,5] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class NewRepository
  location: class com.fakenews.scraper.api.fakenewsScraperApi.service.NewService
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/service/NewService.java:[18,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class New
  location: class com.fakenews.scraper.api.fakenewsScraperApi.service.NewService
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/service/NewService.java:[24,12] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class New
  location: class com.fakenews.scraper.api.fakenewsScraperApi.service.NewService
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/service/NewService.java:[30,21] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class New
  location: class com.fakenews.scraper.api.fakenewsScraperApi.service.NewService
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/service/NewService.java:[30,12] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class New
  location: class com.fakenews.scraper.api.fakenewsScraperApi.service.NewService
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/service/INewService.java:[8,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class New
  location: interface com.fakenews.scraper.api.fakenewsScraperApi.service.INewService
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/service/INewService.java:[9,12] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class New
  location: interface com.fakenews.scraper.api.fakenewsScraperApi.service.INewService
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/service/INewService.java:[10,21] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class New
  location: interface com.fakenews.scraper.api.fakenewsScraperApi.service.INewService
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/service/INewService.java:[10,12] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class New
  location: interface com.fakenews.scraper.api.fakenewsScraperApi.service.INewService
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/controllers/NewController.java:[19,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class New
  location: class com.fakenews.scraper.api.fakenewsScraperApi.controllers.NewController
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/controllers/NewController.java:[27,12] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class New
  location: class com.fakenews.scraper.api.fakenewsScraperApi.controllers.NewController
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/controllers/NewController.java:[3,1] package com.fakenews.commons.fakenewsCommons.models.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/service/NewService.java:[19,22] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class New
  location: class com.fakenews.scraper.api.fakenewsScraperApi.service.NewService
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/controllers/NewController.java:[28,9] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class New
  location: class com.fakenews.scraper.api.fakenewsScraperApi.controllers.NewController
[INFO] 17 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.586 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-09-11T17:23:36+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project fakenewsScraperApi: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/service/NewService.java:[3,55] package com.fakenews.commons.fakenewsCommons.models.dao does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/service/NewService.java:[4,58] package com.fakenews.commons.fakenewsCommons.models.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/service/INewService.java:[3,58] package com.fakenews.commons.fakenewsCommons.models.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/service/NewService.java:[14,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class NewRepository
[ERROR]   location: class com.fakenews.scraper.api.fakenewsScraperApi.service.NewService
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/service/NewService.java:[18,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class New
[ERROR]   location: class com.fakenews.scraper.api.fakenewsScraperApi.service.NewService
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/service/NewService.java:[24,12] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class New
[ERROR]   location: class com.fakenews.scraper.api.fakenewsScraperApi.service.NewService
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/service/NewService.java:[30,21] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class New
[ERROR]   location: class com.fakenews.scraper.api.fakenewsScraperApi.service.NewService
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/service/NewService.java:[30,12] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class New
[ERROR]   location: class com.fakenews.scraper.api.fakenewsScraperApi.service.NewService
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/service/INewService.java:[8,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class New
[ERROR]   location: interface com.fakenews.scraper.api.fakenewsScraperApi.service.INewService
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/service/INewService.java:[9,12] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class New
[ERROR]   location: interface com.fakenews.scraper.api.fakenewsScraperApi.service.INewService
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/service/INewService.java:[10,21] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class New
[ERROR]   location: interface com.fakenews.scraper.api.fakenewsScraperApi.service.INewService
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/service/INewService.java:[10,12] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class New
[ERROR]   location: interface com.fakenews.scraper.api.fakenewsScraperApi.service.INewService
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/controllers/NewController.java:[19,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class New
[ERROR]   location: class com.fakenews.scraper.api.fakenewsScraperApi.controllers.NewController
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/controllers/NewController.java:[27,12] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class New
[ERROR]   location: class com.fakenews.scraper.api.fakenewsScraperApi.controllers.NewController
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/controllers/NewController.java:[3,1] package com.fakenews.commons.fakenewsCommons.models.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/service/NewService.java:[19,22] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class New
[ERROR]   location: class com.fakenews.scraper.api.fakenewsScraperApi.service.NewService
[ERROR] /Users/asax/Documents/workspace-fake-news/fakenewsScraperApi/src/main/java/com/fakenews/scraper/api/fakenewsScraperApi/controllers/NewController.java:[28,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class New
[ERROR]   location: class com.fakenews.scraper.api.fakenewsScraperApi.controllers.NewController
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project fakenewsScraperApi: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1220)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:187)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:61)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

<<<<<< EDIT

I use IntelliJ and the maven module of IntelliJ Ommited the Spring-boot-starter-jpa , i don't know if it's normal.
[image]

Comment: You are saying that you have checked the jar is there in local repo and version is `0.0.4-SNAPSHOT` but the commons pom you have mentioned have `0.0.3-SNAPHOST` as version, is it a typo?

Comment: Yees, soorry , that has been because I have tried to go back to version 3, but it is correct, the pom.xml are in version 0.0.4-SNAPSHOT, I have already edited the ticket

Comment: Delete the `.m2` folder once and then install the common module again, also does it show any error in IDE?

Comment: Also, check this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21283494/1712172) on this question., you might be having same issue.

Comment: I delete the .m2 folder but the problem persist.  I Use IntelliJ , and  the error is the same when I compile with it.

Comment: This seems to be stupid suggestion but try adding packaging `jar` as well :)

Comment: I prefer use maven for CI / CD :(

Comment: You mean, this is happening on CI/CD platform and not in your local machine?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221335/discussion-between-code-mechanic-and-alexxsnjr).

Answer (score 4):

My solution is here :
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-dependency

or you can just delete

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

On the spring-boot project as a dependency

Comment: This worked for me! It did in fact turn out one of my dependencies had the ability to run a spring boot application and thus the plugin mentioned above put all my dependency classes into the BOOT-INF/, after adding <classifier>exec</classifier> the dependent project seemed to compile correctly

Comment: I had the repackage and everything, that <classifier>exec</classifier> made the difference for me. Thnx A lot

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you cannot use a jar as dependency if you build it with the parent `spring-boot-starter-parent`.

Comment: This is possible, we are using it in our projects.

Comment: Thanks you @code_mechanic, I was pretty sure it was possible, but thanks for confirming

Comment: No, I was wrong earlier, @j-fabian-meier was right, I missed it completely, in our project we have skipped the spring-boot normal packaging and packaged it as normal jar.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the problem come from your parent pom, you should create a project structure like

```
application => pom.xml
- common => pom.xml
- API => pom.xml
```

1. application => pom.xml package pom, add modules common, api. you may add a parent to extend spring boot. Dont forget add dependencyManagement
2. common => pom.xml package jar, parent = application. you can add dependency which used for common
3. API => pom.xml package jar, parent = application. You can add spring JPA dependencies here
   then enjoin you common as a shared library same as what you did

Answer (score 1):

It is much better if you create a parent pom.xml and add the commons project as a module.
So you can use the common dependencies in the parent pom and the modules can use them.

Comment: thanks for your opinion, but i want to do an microservices architecture. That's why it's not worth creating a multi-module monolith