# maven, how to skip downloading artifact if already downloaded

Tags: maven

When my project builds, I see it keep hitting the some external repos to download artifacts, but it already did that just a few minutes ago in another build, and the artifacts are in my .m2 folder. How to set  the configuration: only download once (because the rule is that once an artifact is released, it's not updated right? only when I change the version should maven download a new one).

Comment: Dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348603/how-can-i-get-maven-to-stop-attempting-to-check-for-updates-for-artifacts-from-a?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be the default behavior of Maven: If an artifact has previously been downloaded, Maven will not go to remote repository to download again, EXCEPT if the artifact is an SNAPSHOT artifact.

For SNAPSHOT artifacts, the update check is done in interval base on the setting for each repository that is serving snapshots. Set that to a longer time should make your life easier.  Also, do not turn on snapshot for repository that is not serving snapshots.