# In maven how to add a local maven project as a dependency with source code

Tags: java, maven, authentication-flows

https://github.com/OhadR/Authentication-Flows

The client project has a dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ohadr</groupId>
    <artifactId>authentication-flows</artifactId>
    <version>${ohadr.flows.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Which is fetched from online maven repository. The source code for this depdency is [here](https://github.com/OhadR/oAuth2-sample/tree/master/authentication-flows).

I want to make changes in this source code and use that source code as dependency for the client project.

How do I authentication-flows maven project as a dependency in the client application instead of fetching from online maven repo?

Comment: Clone the repository create a branch in git do a `mvn install` and use it in your project?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1348658/2595658):

```
<repository>
  <id>central</id>
  <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
  <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
</repository>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways how you can do this.

1. If your change is a bugfix or a useful feature consider making a pull request to the original project. In order to do that, fork the repository in GitHub, make your changes and create pull request. If this pull request is approved you'll eventually have your changes in central repo. However, this approach will require some patience.
2. You can fork the project, make the changes, rename the group/artifact (if license permits), build it and deploy artifacts to the local/private repository (mvn install/deploy). Then you can add this repository along with corresponding new dependency to your target project.
3. (undesirable approach) You can fork project, make changes, build it and include target jar in your project as maven system scope dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You have all the answers in the README files: it states clearly that the project itself is [here](https://github.com/OhadR/oAuth2-sample/tree/master/authentication-flows). So you can clone it, change whatever you need, build, and use it in your client project.

HTH.